# Add Image to Excel file after pandas.to_excel()

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-excel, xlsxwriter

I am using `xlsxwriter` as the `engine` that I pass to `pandas.ExcelWriter`. I have a DataFrame and I call `to_excel()` on it passing the writer that I've previously acquired. I then try grabbing the worksheet using `get_worksheet_by_name()`, which seems to work well, and then calling `worksheet.insert_image()` to insert an image.

This isn't working. I have the supposition that `to_excel()` causes the worksheet to be written and thus not available for mutation later on. Is this correct? If so, would I have to have a manual process for reading every cell in the DataFrame and writing it to Excel myself using `xlsxwriter` so that I can do the image stuff too? Or is there a way to tell `to_excel()` not to finish writing the sheet?

Comment: `to_excel()` doesn't write the sheet and lock it. Indeed you can use `to_excel()` multiple times to write multiple dataframes to the same sheet (just need to change the 'startrow' so they don't write over each other). As you have, executing Xlsxwriter worksheet commands should also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code example will insert a dataframe and the image

The worksheet assignment is just;
`worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']`

```
import pandas as pd

data_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': ['Appple', 'Banana', 'Mango',
                           'Dragon Fruit', 'Musk melon', 'grapes'],
                           'Sales in kg': [20, 30, 15, 10, 50, 40]})

with pd.ExcelWriter("foo.xlsx") as writer:
    data_frame.to_excel(writer,
                        sheet_name="Sheet1",
                        index=False)

    writer.sheets['Sheet1'].insert_image("D2", "pic.png")
```

However if you were to use

```
workbook = writer.book

worksheet = workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('Sheet1')
worksheet.insert_image("D2", "pic.png")
```

instead of `writer.sheets`, that would work as well.

[image: Example screenshot]

Comment: The problem that I had was related to using `column` to export specific columns. The calculation for getting the correct column to work with was off. I had to adjust my calculation to work with the actually exported columns. Your sample was very helpful in validating my approach. I even used `set_row_pixels()` and `set_column_pixels()` to better place the image.